# How to find match and print it

Tags: python, regex

How to find match and print it. I am using regex to achieve but not able to match

I have a string where I need to find match and print

```
s='flowerflowflight'
```

**Expected output :**

```
fl
```

**My code :**

```
import re 

print(re.search(r'[a-z]\+',s))
```

Comment: what do you think `\+` does?

Comment: Even if you fixed that, what would `[a-z]+` match? Definitely not only `fl`.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. It's difficult to understand this question. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use compile:

```
import re

# you get tru or false
patterns = ['fl']
s = 'flowerflowflight'
for pattern in patterns:
    if re.search(pattern, s):
        print("found a match")
    else:
        print("not found a match")

# print a list of match
s='flowerflowflight'
pattern = re.compile('fl')
result=pattern.findall(s)
print('first list element',result[0])

# print the first match
result = re.match('fl', s)
print('first match', result.group())

# all match emements in a list
s1 = ['flowerflowflight','fl']
for elem in s1:
    p = re.match('fl', elem)
    print('all matches in a list', p.group())
    
# print all matches  
s = 'flowerflowflight'
res = re.finditer('fl', s)
for hit in res:
    print('iter all matches', hit.group())
```

Output:

```
found a match
first list element fl
first match fl
all matches in a list fl
all matches in a list fl
iter all matches fl
iter all matches fl
iter all matches fl
```